# Moderate Facebook comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

It seems I'm unable to moderate the Facebook comments of the Facebook comments plug-in.

Bellow the code that we initialy created. As you can see an appId is associated with it. Also, if you vist the page (http://amstelveenz.nl/armageddon/) there is one Facebook comment.

```
            <div id="fb-root"></div>
            <script>
                window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                    FB.init({
                        appId: '1389836761336596',
                        xfbml: true,
                        version: 'v2.3'
                    });
                };

                (function (d, s, id) {
                    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                        return;
                    }
                    js = d.createElement(s);
                    js.id = id;
                    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
            </script>
            <div class="facebook-comments">
                <!-- facebook comments -->
                <div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" data-width="100%" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
                <!-- einde facebook comments -->

            </div>
```

When visiting https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments to manage the comments I'm unable to the comments made on the website.

Also when visiting the page I don't see the moderator view.

The solution I came across quite often was to add the following lines:

```
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="1389836761336596"/>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="712359589"/>
```

Ofcourse with my app_id and user_id. This also didn't result in a solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify fb:admins on your site to tell us who should be able to admin the comments

Comment: I got one admin configured as shown above. (for some reason those lines disappeared in from the post)

Comment: Looks correct. I would suggest filing a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs